# Image / video hosting which can provide original filename as link

Tags: html

i'm trying to embed image/video in my homepage :

```
<img src = "my_image" >
```

or

```
<video width="500px" height="500px" controls="controls"/> 
    <source src="my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

This function works fine but the problem is about the image/video hosting. If i put my images on flickr, google drive or dropbox etc. They don't give me link to the file using the filename but they use their internal id :

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1I_gBhobUvVWXC7BsWKu7ozKdsHzN3qSt7Y
```

If i create dynamic homepage using database, the image/video to be retrieved has to be in sequential format for example (i simply use google sheet as database for storing the image names ) :

```
image_001.png
image_002.png
```

or

```
video_001.mp4
video_002.mp4
```

My webpage will request the filename from database (google sheet) then it will generate dynamic link to the image.

The problem using ID to link to my images, if let say i have 800 images then i have to input manually all the ID into my database.

How is it possible ? Does anyone know any hosting that can provide this link-byname feature ? Or is there any tricks? something like getting the list of all image id and its corresponding image without requesting the ID one by one , so later if i have to use those IDs, i can input easily to my database/table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just upload the assets along with your static files on your hosting

Comment: I'm not hosting my website anywhere , I'm using google app script (script.google.com) to generate my web app interface. So the images will be uploaded into google drive or dropbox or flicker or anything like that but so far i can't find the one that still can give me access to the filename.

Comment: okay so take all of your assets and put them in a folder called assets then go to netlify.com, signup or login and go to the sites tab then just drag and drop that folder tada you now have a cdn to access your images go to the link and add /assets/FILE_NAME

Comment: Thanks seems starting to work, but where's the file manager. Trying to modify the files/folder i've uploaded but couldn't find it.

Comment: yeah there isnt one if you wanna make a change do it to the folder on your system then redeploy it by going to deploy tab of your site